# Sum of values in a list

Tags: sum, netlogo

I have students (turtles) and 30 schools (patches). For each student I have created a variable (utilities) from a utility function containing the utility of each school (so 30 values for each student). The problem is that I cannot generate a new variable that sums the 30 utility values for each student.

```
turtles-own
[
  
  utilities; schools' utilities for each individual
  cumul;
]
patches-own
[
  
  schoolachievement_2 ; overall mean school achievement
  
]
 to go
ask turtles [ utility ]

to utility
  set utilities [ school-utility ] of patches with [ schoolachievement_2 > 0 ]
  set cumul  reduce +  [ utilities ] of turtles
end 
end
```

`reduce +` gives the error: '+ expected input to be a number but got the list'.

If I use `sum` instead of `reduce +` I get 0 for all students.
If instead of `reduce +` I use `map sum` I get the error: 'SUM expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead'.

Comment: Something weird is going on with your syntax around `cumul`. You want to do `set cumul <...>` first and then `show cumul` next. Or `let cumul` depending on whether or not it is a local variable

Comment: @LeirsW thank you for your comment. I get the same error message when I `set cumul` . I have edited the code and used the latter to avoid confusion. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

LeirsW is correct about the syntax problem. But there are actually a number of issues here.  First, I assume that `school-utility` is either a patch (school) variable or a reporter that uses other patch variables to return a number. Since it does not seem to know what turtle called it, the answer will likely be the same for all turtles.  Is that what you want, or have I missed something?  Next, in the `utility` routine, the first line has the turtle create a list of utilities (which could be empty if no patches satisfy the `with` condition).  In the next line you have each turtle try to sum the utilities of **all** turtles, not just its own.  Therefore, you are summing a list of lists, not just a simple list.  There are a couple of ways you might do that.
The first is

```
let cumul sum [sum utilities] of turtles
```

This has each turtle sum its utilities and pass that to the culumlative summation.
Another is to collapse the list of lists to a simple list with `sentence`, then to sum it.

```
let cumul sum sentence [utilities] of turtles
```

But, both these solutions beg the question of why each turtle is being asked to do the same thing.  The calculation of cumul should take place outside of `utility` so it is only done once.

Of course perhaps `cumul` should just be for the individual turtle?  If so, you only need

```
let cumul sum utilities
show cumul
```

and you have it in the right place.

Charles

Comment: Dear @Charles thank you. What I need is `cumul` for the individual turtle and your suggestion `let cumul sum utilities` does the job. In case you are interested, `school-utility` is a reporter that uses both patch and turtle variables to return different numbers for different turtles and different schools (patches). Thank you, Nic

Comment: @NicolaPensiero Nice to see that you got the answer you needed. Could you please upvote this answer? In doing so, you accept it and the answer will be marked as solved so other people know they dont need to come in anymore to take a look

Comment: @LeirsW thanks for the suggestion. I checked 'answer was useful', is that what you mean?

Comment: @NicolaPensiero Weird. That is indeed what I was referring to but it seems like stackoverflow didn't register you clicking it, otherwise it would have an upvote and a checkmark for solved

Comment: Perhaps it is because i do not have enough feedback or something